# Neo4J Accidental Shutdown or wrong configuration?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, neo4j

**ORIGNAL POST**

Let me start off with my code. This is the fragment of code where the error appears.

```
DatabaseModuleInterface dbModule = new DatabaseModuleImpl();
System.out.println(dbModule.getDb());
Traverser t = dbModule.getGraphTree(usernode);

System.out.println("DBMODULE = " + dbModule.toString());
System.out.println("USERNODE = " + usernode);
System.out.println("TRAVERSER1 = " + dbModule.getGraphTree(usernode));

    System.out.println("T IS NOT NULL");
    if (t.nodes() != null) {
        System.out.println("T NODES IS NOT NULL");
        for (Node node : t.nodes()) {
            if (node != null) {
                System.out.println("NODE IS NOT NULL");
            } else {
                System.out.println("NODE IS NULL");
            }
        }
    }
```

Which returns

```
INFO: EmbeddedGraphDatabase [C:\impactordb]
INFO: DBMODULE = be.archimiddle.impactor.modules.database.interfaces.DatabaseModuleImpl@bed5ea
INFO: USERNODE = Node[241]
INFO: TRAVERSER1 = org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.TraverserImpl@ce2016
INFO: T IS NOT NULL
INFO: T NODES IS NOT NULL
```

And then comes the error with following stack trace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.ReadTransaction.nodeLoadLight(ReadTransaction.java:86)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.persistence.PersistenceManager.loadLightNode(PersistenceManager.java:82)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeManager.getLightNode(NodeManager.java:423)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeManager.getNodeForProxy(NodeManager.java:440)
at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase$4.lookup(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:660)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeProxy.getRelationships(NodeProxy.java:98)
at org.neo4j.kernel.StandardExpander$RegularExpander.doExpand(StandardExpander.java:579)
at org.neo4j.kernel.StandardExpander$RelationshipExpansion.iterator(StandardExpander.java:194)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.TraversalBranchWithState.expandRelationshipsWithoutChecks(TraversalBranchWithState.java:78)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.TraversalBranchImpl.expandRelationships(TraversalBranchImpl.java:104)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.StartNodeTraversalBranch.next(StartNodeTraversalBranch.java:46)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.AsOneStartBranch.next(AsOneStartBranch.java:100)
at org.neo4j.kernel.PreorderDepthFirstSelector.next(PreorderDepthFirstSelector.java:52)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.TraverserIterator.fetchNextOrNull(TraverserIterator.java:64)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.TraverserIterator.fetchNextOrNull(TraverserIterator.java:33)
at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.PrefetchingIterator.hasNext(PrefetchingIterator.java:55)
at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorWrapper.hasNext(IteratorWrapper.java:42)
at com.archimiddle.impactor.action.navigation.ViewGraphAction.getGraphTree(ViewGraphAction.java:107)
```

This line #107 is the following line in the snippet:

```
for(Node node : t.nodes()){
```

I've checked everything for null values, and couldn't find anything. If anybody could help me, it would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

I use this method to show the tree hidden in my graph. I know the method works because I can see my graph.

It's only that after I added nodes using the Neo4jgraph from tinkerpop blueprints, that I no longer can use the method to view my graph. In order for Gremlin to actually add the nodes to my Neo4J graph I have to call either a shutdown or a stopTransaction before the nodes are commited.

```
Neo4jgraph graph = new Neo4jGraph(my_graphdatabaseservice);
//ADD NODES HERE
//I USED TO DO THIS
neo4jgraph.shutdown();
//NOW I DO THIS
neo4jgraph.stopTransaction(Conclusion.SUCCESS);
```

I have to do either one of those two or my nodes won't be commmited. And I have to add them using Blueprints for a very specific reason.

I'm suspecting it has something to do with this since it only happens after I do this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not related with the code-snippet you posted. Everything there is working fine.

The problem is with your neo4j implementation.

Try adding the following parameters to your neo4j configuration

- config.cache_classes = true
- config.threadsafe!

Comment: I know how to attach a property file to my embedded Neo4J, but atm I am using the default configuration you get from the GraphDatabaseFactory. What other settings would I need to incorporate in my properties file so that the two settings you provided are the only ones that change...

Comment: I added the cache_classes = true, but it didn't help. I thought the threadsafe! was only for start-up?

I have added something to the Original Post which may shed some more light on the situation.

Comment: Ok. So you were actually shutting down the database. This explains the resulting NPE in the Neo4j ReadTranscation class. And I fear that stopTransaction causes a similar problem.

If it is only about committing your nodes - did you try the following: neo4jgraph.setTransactionMode(TransactionalGraph.Mode.AUTOMATIC);

Comment: In AUTOMATIC mode, transactions are basically ignored, in the sense that each item that gets created is immediately persisted in the underlying Graph Database.

Comment: I'm using Blueprints for a high speed import of several thousand nodes. That's why I want to do it in one transaction. But somehow I got things working using your two configuration parameters and by clearing the neo4J cache manually after an import.

Comment: Yeah thanks a bunch for that; You've been a genuine life saver today :P